# Magento cannot create MassAction via OrderController. Whats up?

Tags: php, magento

I am getting a little irritated by this code not working. Any advice?

The newly created massAction is not found, but rather a 404?

**config.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <SNH_ShipMailInvoice>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </SNH_ShipMailInvoice>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <events>
            <!-- Event to attach observer to -->
            <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <SNH_ShipMailInvoice>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <!-- Observer location (e.g. SW/GridExample/Model) -->
                        <class>SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Model_Observer</class>
                        <!-- Function to call -->
                        <method>addMassAction</method>
                    </SNH_ShipMailInvoice>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
        </events>
    </global>

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <!-- Override Adminhtml module here. -->
                        <SNH_ShipMailInvoice before="Mage_Adminhtml">SNH_ShipMailInvoice</SNH_ShipMailInvoice>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

`Observer.php` is working fine and shows the option (below):

```
<?php
class SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Model_Observer
{
    public function addMassAction($observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
        // Check if this block is a MassAction block
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction) {
            // Check if we're dealing with the Orders grid
            if ($block->getParentBlock() instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid) {
                // The first parameter has to be unique, or you'll overwrite the old action.
                $block->addItem('ship_mail_invoice', array(
                        'label' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship, Mail and Invoice'),
                        'url' => $block->getUrl('*/*/shipmailinvoice'),
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

Now when I select the newly created option I receive a 404 not found error. The URL  is something like `admin/sales_order/shipmailinvoice/key/`.

The `OrderController.php` file is in `SNH/ShipMailInvoice/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php`:

```
require_once('Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php');

class SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{

    public function shipmailinvoiceAction()
    {
        // This should be called when the url has the pattern '*/*/attack' (as it does
        // when displaying my custom tab) however clicking this tab gives a 404.
        die('<h1>attackAction()</h1>');
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed!

Routers should be:

    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <!-- Override Adminhtml module here. -->
                        <SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml</SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>


and OrderController in /app/code/local/SNH/ShipMailInvoice/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File location and XML naming is very specific

in config.xml:

> ```
> <admin>
>     <routers>
>         <adminhtml>
>             <args>
>                 <modules>
>                     <!-- Override Adminhtml module here. -->
>                     <SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml before="Mage_Adminhtml">SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml</SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml>
>                 </modules>
>             </args>
>         </adminhtml>
>     </routers>
> </admin>
> ```

And OrderController should be placed here:

> /app/code/local/SNH/ShipMailInvoice/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php

Starting with exactly this

> require_once "Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php";
>
> ```
> class SNH_ShipMailInvoice_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
> {
>
>     public function shipmailinvoiceAction()
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Case matters here, compare
`admin/sales_order/shipmailinvoice/key/`
and
`SNH/ShipMailInvoice/controllers/Adminhtml/Sales/OrderController.php`. You should define url as `admin/sales_order/shipMailInvoice/key/` or rename file and class accordingly.

Comment: I changed url to: ShipMailInvoice (upper caps per word) which resolves to admin/sales_order/ShipMailInvoice/key/

still the 404 error

Comment: Hmm, are you sure appropriate `<acl> <resources> <admin>` section for your action is present in your module `adminhtml.xml`? Also, after adding such section you must logout and login to admin because acl for current logged user are stored in session.