# Magento - Add Mass Action to Sales > Orders Grid

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

**Edit 4/4/12**

**I STILL HAVE ONE QUESTION:**

I solved my issue but it adds my option at the top of the list. How can I sort it to my my option to the **bottom** of the list?

Please see answer for contents of my working `config.xml` file...

---

I'm looking for in depth help here because I've been at this for quite a while now and seem to be getting nowhere.

**Background**
I was looking to make a printable RMA form for our customers to make it easier on them to Return/Exchange items.

I did this with the help of this extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/admin-order-printing-extension.html
*(Please download this to see the directory structure if needed)*

It adds a button to the order and then I went in and edited the form/form layout so that it was an RMA (or has RMA content).

Everything is working great, however, we have to go into each order and press the button in order for it to print.

We really need a `Mass Action` in order to make it more efficient and useful.

**Problem**
I've tried to different ways to get this to work but I really need help on this. Most recently I've tried to follow this tutorial (http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/) using the second method of `events` but I can't seem to get this to work.

Can someone please explain in more depth (this last method I've tried) so that I can get it working with this module???

I've added this in the `config.xml`(according to the tutorial)

```
<events>
    <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        <observers>
            <orderprint_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                 <class>orderprint/observer</class>
                 <method>addRmaAction</method>
            </orderprint_core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </observers>
    </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
 </events>
```

And in `Nastnet/OrderPrint/Model/Observer.php` I've added this (according to the tutorial)

```
<?php class Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer {
public function addRmaAction($observer) {
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $block->addItem('pdfrma_order', array(
            'label' => 'Print RMA',
            'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('nastnet/controller/action'),
        ));
    }
} }
```

*(Sorry for the messy code above - the only way I could get it highlighted)*

**EDIT 1 (4/2/12)**
This is my module's config.xml file. I've had to go with the rewrite/override method as of right now (deleting my attempts at using events). If you see anything, including the exact structure of what it would need to be please let me know...

Minus the `<config>` tags:

```
<modules>
    <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
        <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
</modules>

<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_grid>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid> <!-- WORKIING METHOD -->
                <sales_order_view>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <rewrite>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
            <from><![CDATA[#/\w+/sales_order/print/#]]></from>
            <to>/orderprint/order/print/</to>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
    </rewrite>
    <models>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
            <class>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model</class>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </models>
    <pdf>
        <order>
            <default>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_default</default>
            <grouped>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_grouped</grouped>
        </order>
    </pdf>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
             <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Nastnet_OrderPrint</module>
                <!-- This is used when "catching" the rewrite above -->
                <frontName>orderprint</frontName>
            </args>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </routers>
```

Comment: Make sure if your module is loaded or not, also check if there are any errors in your module.

Comment: is your class well defined in the config.xml? paste it here so we can check for any typo

Comment: OSdave - I pasted my config.xml above. I've deleted my attempts so far as to the "Event" method. I've tried multiple ways using this (http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/) method 2 and this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9034843/magento-cannot-create-massaction-via-ordercontroller-whats-up). Neither one gets me the new label in the dropdown like it does when I just extend it (as above)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured out the correct handles and everything in order for this to work (with the help of this article: http://mydons.com/simple-example-using-magento-event-observer/)

In the config.xml file, I had to make new `<adminhtml>` handles after the `<config>` handles. This got me to the right "depth". Here is the entire config.xml file minus the `<config>` handles (cause it won't paste correctly):

```
<modules>
    <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
        <version>0.1.3</version>
    </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
</modules>
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addRmaAction</method>
                </Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
<global>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Block_Sales_Order_View</sales_order_view>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
    <rewrite>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
            <from><![CDATA[#/\w+/sales_order/print/#]]></from>
            <to>/orderprint/order/print/</to>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint_OrderController>
    </rewrite>
    <models>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
            <class>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model</class>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </models>
    <pdf>
        <order>
            <default>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_default</default>
            <grouped>Nastnet_OrderPrint/order_pdf_items_order_grouped</grouped>
        </order>
    </pdf>
</global>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <Nastnet_OrderPrint>
             <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Nastnet_OrderPrint</module>
                <!-- This is used when "catching" the rewrite above -->
                <frontName>orderprint</frontName>
            </args>
        </Nastnet_OrderPrint>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

This is the part that I needed and it is finally correct here:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
            <observers>
                <Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>addRmaAction</method>
                </Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

It points to my observer file (based on the correct event) here: **app/code/local/Nastnet/OrderPrint/Model/Observer.php**. This obviously then holds my `addRmaAction`.

**I STILL HAVE ONE QUESTION:**

This puts my option at the top of the list. How can I sort it to my my option to the **bottom** of the list?

*Contents of `Observer.php`*

```
<?php
class Nastnet_OrderPrint_Model_Observer
{
public function addRmaAction($observer)
{   
    $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
    if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
        && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
    {
        $block->addItem('rmamassprint', array(
            'label' => 'Print Return/Exchange',
            'url' => Mage::app()->getStore()->getUrl('orderprint/order/pdfRma'),
        ));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: The observer method is by far going to be the most modular way of doing this especially for the sales order grid as there are about a thousand extensions that add to that block. 

Instead of using get_class($block) == '...' in your check, I recommend using $block instanceOf Mage_Adminhtml_Block_... This way if another module rewrites the block, as long as they extended the original it should still work.

Answer (score 0):

For starters did you confirm whether or not your observer is being called? Just by adding a `Mage::log("Observer called");`
and watching the system.log file..

Comment: I don't think it's even being called because I put that in the `Observer.php` file and nothing shows up in the system.log file. I originally thought that there's something wrong with the `config.xml` paths but I don't know - that's why I posted here. Still bangin the head against the table....

Comment: Follow this tutorial to make a simple observer: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/customizing_magento_using_event-observer_method. Once you determine that the observer is working you could modify the event to which ever event you wanted, and you could do the same for the method add anything you want in the method once you determine that it is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working tutorial for adding mass action to Sales > Order Grid:
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/adding-new-mass-action-to-admin-grid-in-magento/

Try the 2nd approach(using event-observer method) which seems to be more upgrade proof way.
Thanks

Comment: MagePsycho, I've been trying to follow your tutorial on it (linked above in the original post). However, I cannot get it to work. It doesn't seem to pick it up the event at all. Do you have any tips on trouble shooting it or do you have any ideas as to why it may not be working?

Comment: Make sure if you have <events> block inside of <config><adminhtml>...</adminhtml></config> node.

Comment: Yes, the `<events>` tag is inside the `<config><global><blocks><adminhtml>` tags

Comment: Nope it should be inside of <config><adminhtml> instead of <config><global><blocks><adminhtml>.Noee the depth,you will know the mistake.

Comment: Ok. Now I have `<config><adminhtml><events>`. Still not working